# Multi level divider

Tags: jquery, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

## Java script

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['angular.filter']);

app.controller('homeCtrl', function($scope) {

    $scope.data = {
        "error": false,
        "events": [{
            "id": 1,
            "title": "scenario1",
            "flag":"locked",
            "date": "2014"
        }, {
            "id": 2,
            "title": "scenario2",
            "flag":"unlocked",
            "date": "2014"
        }, {
            "id": 3,
            "title": "scenario3",
            "flag":"locked",
            "date": "2015"
        }, {
            "id": 4,
            "title": "scenario4",
            "flag":"unlocked",
            "date": "2016"
        }, {
            "id": 5,
            "title": "scenario5",
            "flag":"unlocked",
            "date": "2017"
        }, {
            "id": 6,
            "title": "scenario6",
            "flag":"unlocked",
            "date": "2014"
        }, {
            "id": 7,
            "title": "scenario7",
            "flag":"unlocked",
            "date": "2015"
        }, {
            "id": 7,
            "title": "scenario8",
            "flag":"locked",
            "date": "2015"
        }]
    }

});
```

I am able to do group wise split but I am trying for both Year and Flag wise
I am trying for this output any suggestion please suggest

**2014 - locked**
scenario1

**2014 -unlocked**
scenario2
scenario6

**2015 - locked**
scenario3
scenario8

**2015 - unlocked**
scenario7

**2016 - unlocked**
scenario4

**2017 - unlocked**
scenario5

And the html pages is,

```
<div ng-app="app">
     <div ng-controller="homeCtrl">
          <div ng-repeat="(key, value) in data.events | groupBy: 'date'">
               <div> <h1> {{key}}</h1> </div>
                    <a class="item item-thumbnail-left" href="#/app/event/{{event.id}}" ng-repeat="event in value">
                          <h3>{{event.title}}</h3>
                     </a>
                 </div>
            </div>
      </div>
</div>
```

Comment: <div ng-app="app">  
<div ng-controller="homeCtrl"><div ng-repeat="(key, value) in data.events | groupBy: 'date'">
      
      <div>
        <h1> {{key}}</h1>
      </div>

      <a class="item item-thumbnail-left" href="#/app/event/{{event.id}}" ng-repeat="event in value">
        <h3>{{event.title}}</h3>
      </a>
    </div>
 

  </div>

Comment: The expected output you have shown does not have any built-in format. Do you just want to display the output like that??

Comment: I have modified the output In which I want Thanks for your support @Gilsha

Comment: with the above html code I am able to get Year wise.I am not able to do both year wise and flag wise

Answer (score 1):

### Try this

```
<div ng-repeat="(key, value) in data.events | groupBy: 'date'">
    <div ng-repeat="(key,value) in value | groupBy: 'flag'">
        <b>{{value[0].date}}-{{key}}</b>
        <div ng-repeat="val in value">  
            {{val.title}}
        </div>
        <br>
    </div>
</div>
```